# Use output of multiple views in one view with single url

Tags: django, django-views, backend, web-development-server

So i am fairly new to Django and here is what i want:
Say i have Three Views, View 1, 2 and 3. Each one with their own Template, Http response ,context and everything.

Now i know how to Use 3 separate URLs for each view but what i would like to do is Just have one url for say View 3 and  Outputs of View 2 and 3 are merged or concatenated whatever you wanna say in the view 3 itself.

I am doing this because i have a lot of context and doing one view and single template results in a large code.
At the moment i am using Class Views but i am open to you use function views.

I want to know if there is a way i can Get Output/Results of View 1 and 2 in View 3 combined.

Note: If someone is familiar  with React and the components thats kind of what i am trying to do. Like making two components separately and then have a container component to call them.
P.S. i am not using react i just thought this will explain what i am trying to do.

Comment: You could [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include) a template within another, each can be passed context variables so it has the data to be rendered, or reused in a loop for instance. Another option could be to load the other views in AJAX from the first one.

Comment: Thankyou this actually solved 80% of my problem. Unfortunately i still have to pass a lot of context from a single. I read about inclusion tag which might help but for now i am sticking with your suggestion.